# shouldFailWithCause fails test

Tags: grails, groovy, junit

In grails 1.3.5 application I have to test method that throws an exception, but this test fails:

```
        shouldFailWithCause(MyException) {
            vb.doStuff person
        }
```

The message is: 
**junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Closure should have failed with an exception caused by type MyException, instead found these Exceptions:
MyException: Here comes the message of exception.**

It throws the correct exception but fails the test. What is going wrong?

Edit:

```
public void doStuff(person) {
        if (!canPersonDoStuff(person)) {
            throw new MyException("Here comes the message of exception")
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code under test?

Comment: It's in the question. The interesting part is a message that tell that it cought exception but with message.

Comment: I meant how does `doStuff()` look like in real.

Comment: Added edit to orig question

Answer (score 3):

`shouldFailWithCause` looks for the `cause` of the exception instead of the exception itself. You can get your assertion to work if you add throw `MyException` as the cause of Exception.

```
public void doStuff(person) {
    if (!canPersonDoStuff(person)) {
        throw new Exception(new MyException("The message of my exception"))
        //or throw new Exception(cause: new MyException("message"))
    }
}
```

I would rather use whatever logic you have right now in `doStuff()` but assert with `shouldFail{..}` instead of `shouldFailWithCause{..}` because the former checks for the exact exception that is thrown.

```
shouldFail(MyException) {
    vb.doStuff person
}
```